# javascript: open all links to pdf on a page in new window

Tags: javascript

I have a site that builds the pages dynamically. It's a SharePoint site. The site contains a lot of document libraries. The libraries contain word, excel and PDF documents. When a user clicks on a document, the document opens in the client application for office documents only. PDFs simply open in the same window. when people close the window containing the document, they close the site. I'm trying to use javascript to onload add target="_blank" to the PDF links.

So far I have:

```
window.onload = function(){
    l=document.links.length;
    for(i = 0; i<l; i++) {
        n = document.links[i].href.indexOf(".pdf");

        if (n > 0){
            document.links[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank');
        }
    }
}
```

This code sort of works as some of the pdf links load in a new window as expected, some load in the parent window and some links load in both a new window and the parent. How do I tell the browser not to load in the parent window and only in the new window?

This is what I want to achieve:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<a href="a.pdf">a.pdf</a><br /><br />
<a href="b.html">b.html</a><br /><br />
<a href="c.pdf">c.pdf</a><br /><br />

<script>
window.onload = function(){
    l=document.links.length;
    for(i = 0; i<l; i++) {
        n = document.links[i].href.indexOf(".pdf");

        if (n > 0){
            document.links[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank');
        }
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem I'm running into is that sharepoint document libraries are modifying the link behavior such that the javascript does not make then open in a new window. Below is an example of a link from a document library:

```
<a onfocus="OnLink(this)" href="https://rcd.sharepoint.com/HR/HR%20Policy%20Manual.pdf" onmousedown="return VerifyHref(this,event,'0','','')" onclick="return DispEx(this,event,'TRUE','FALSE','FALSE','','0','','','','','331','0','0','0x7fffffffffffffff','','')">HR Policy Manual</a>
```

Comment: It should not open in both windows, you need to show an example of this happening. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example There's probably something else going on.

Comment: unclear how it would load in the parent window when you set target to blank

Comment: Now I can't find the PDF opening in both the parent and child. Most of the links open in the parent. I've found only one link that opens in a child window. The bigger problem is that when pressing the back button after loading the PDF in the parent, I get the message that the page has expired and it needs to be loaded again (IE only not chrome, Firefox).

Comment: it appears to have something to do with the document libraries that SharePoint provides as the site navigation links work as expected. links in the library appear as: 
<a onfocus="OnLink(this)" href="https://rcda145.sharepoint.com/HR/HR%20Policy%20Manual.pdf" onmousedown="return VerifyHref(this,event,'0','','')" onclick="return DispEx(this,event,'TRUE','FALSE','FALSE','','0','','','','','331','0','0','0x7fffffffffffffff','','')">HR Policy Manual</a>  now i need to see what is going on with the functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following JavaScript to get links containing "pdf" to open in a new window:

```
window.onload = function(){
    l=document.links.length;
    for(i = 0; i<l; i++) {
        n = document.links[i].href.indexOf(".pdf");

        if (n > 0){
            document.links[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank');
        }
    }
}
```

I then noticed that document libraries were using a DispEx() javascript function on click of document links which negated the first bit of code. I had to overload the function with my own functionality.

```
function DispEx(a){
    if (a.href.endsWith('.pdf')){
        window.open(a);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Using both pieces of JavaScript in a content editor web part, I got PDF documents to open in a new window and all other links/documents to load in the same window.

Comment: why are you checkin for a positive index of the `.pdf` string ? why not check for `.endsWith('.pdf')` ? your check should fail If there's a filename called `somedummyfile.pdf.something.png` (which is a `.png` image) or any other formatted file

Comment: You make a good point. I should check for the extension at the end of file name. I will update the code example above.

Comment: Can you try the solution I provided? it should work.

Comment: Thanks, but accepting your own answer isn't a SO practice.

Comment: What do you mean by, "accepting your own answer isn't a SO practice"? It is the answer and the code that I went with.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have access to all elements for ahead with capturing all clicks on the page. Use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) with enabled capturing for handling event. Test whether it's anchor tag and proceed to new page by own with code below:

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    if (e.target.localName == 'a') {
        var url = e.target.getAttribute('href');
        e.stopPropagation();
        // You can place extra checks here.
        var tab = window.open(url, '_blank');
        tab.focus();
    }
}, true)
```

Comment: I hate to say it, but that code still loads the links in the same window.

Comment: @RCDAWebmaster that would be nice to have  minimal reproducible example

Comment: I added a code snippet in my original question to show what I was hoping to achieve and a note that SharePoint document libraries render the javascript useless as it has an onclick event using DispEx which I don't understand.

Comment: @RCDAWebmaster Updated to usage of addEventListener, try to use following approach.

Answer (score 1):

### Do

Here is what I would do, I think I would collect the `anchors` and loop over them to check if the `href`s ends with `.pdf` and then add a function on all the `.pdf` links

### Don't

Don't check for pdf files with `.indexOf('.pdf')`. Your check should fail If there's a filename called `somedummyfile.pdf.something.png` (which is a .png image) or any other formatted file.

---

**Note** that, new window might be blocked at user's end if they are using add-blockers.

Here is the Snippet:

```js
function modifyLinks() {
  let links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  let properties = 'height=' + window.innerHeight + ',width=' + window.innerWidth + ',' + 'scrollbars=yes,status=yes';
  for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    if (links[i].href.endsWith('.pdf')) {
      // links[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank'); // if you want to open them in new tab;
      console.log(links[i].href);
      links[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.open(this.href, '_blank', properties);
      })
    }
  }
}

window.addEventListener('load', modifyLinks);
```

```html
<a href="somefile_1.pdf">File 1</a>
<a href="somefile_2.pdf">File 2</a>
<a href="somefile_3.pdf">File 3</a>
<a href="test.html">HTML Link</a>
<a href="some_file.ai">Some Other file</a>
```